# How to secure Postgres client certificates on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ssl, heroku

I'm connecting a Rails app hosted on Heroku, to an external PostgreSQL database using SSL certificates for authentication.

This requires three files: (1)the signed certificate (2)the key (3)the root ca certificate.

The signed cert and the root cert can both be added to the git repo, but the key must be kept secure.

For passwords, we would use ENV/'Config Vars' to keep things safe .... but how do I secure the key file?

I asked Heroku themselves, but they said this was "an issue that falls outside the nature of the Heroku Support policy."

So I'm asking the experts instead

Comment: One way to avoid commiting the key file would I guess be to add the key to a ENV var and then setup a git post push hook that dumps the ENV var into a file (since the file system is reset every time you push). You can use the `PGSSLKEY` ENV var to set the file path. I suspect that there could be an easier solution though.

Comment: As an alternative to git hooks you could use a [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) and the [`release:`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase) phase. The advantage is that it will be triggered if any of the config vars change.

Comment: Thanks @max. Using an ENV var was a great idea.  Both post push hook and Profile release: worked well on deploy, but not on re-start or scaling.  I added the code to generate the key file in `config/application.rb` and it works consistently now.  If you want to make an 'official' answer I'll accept it as the correct one :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to avoid commiting the key file would I guess be to add the key to a ENV var and then setup a git hook or Procfile command that dumps the ENV var into a file (since the file system is reset every time you push). You can use the PGSSLKEY ENV var to set the file path.